# Proof in the "Reaching Agreement in the Presence of Faults"

Tags: distributed-systems, information-theory, fault-tolerance

I am reading the ["Reaching Agreement in the Presence of Faults", M. Pease et al](https://lamport.azurewebsites.net/pubs/reaching.pdf) and trying to understand their proof for the $n \geq 3m+1$ case.

In the induction step $m \gt 0$ it says the following:

> ... Any   other set satisfying these requirements,  moreover, must
> contain a  nonfaulty processor (since it must be  of   size $\gt \frac{(n  +  m)}{2}$, and $n  \ge 3m  + 1$) and
> must  therefore  also yield  $V_q$ as  the common   value.  The  algorithm thus  terminates  at  step
> (1),  and $p$    records  $V_q$ and  $q$  as required...

This is not obvious to me and seems wrong. For example, assume $Q$ is a set of processors of length $\ \ge \frac{n+m}{2}$ where only one is a faulty processor $f$ and rest are nonfaulty. Now we consider all strings $w$ of length $\le m$ of this set and in particular $\sigma_p(pfq)$. Since $f$ is a faulty processor it can return any value, not necessarily $V_q$, thus there cannot be a common value between all $w$ strings. This means that any set $Q$ that contains at least one nonfaulty processor cannot be used at all.

Is my understanding wrong?

Answer (score 1):

What is important about the paragraph above are the few lines that proceed it in the proof.  This is all under the context of *"First note that if q is nonfaulty"*.  If we know that q is nonfaulty, then we know that q has sent the same value of its internal state, V<sub>q</sub>, to every processor.  Therefore, if we have a subset of processors that meet the requirements of all reporting to p that all of them have received the same value from everyone else in the subset for V<sub>q</sub>, and the subset includes at least 1 nonfaulty processor **and** we are in the scenario that q is nonfaulty, then we know no matter which subset this happens to be, there can only be one value of V<sub>q</sub> which could possibly be used in generating such a set (i.e. the true internal state of q)

Answer (score 0):

The word "requirements" is the key to solve the question. the requirements mean:
(1) some subset Q ofPofsize >(n + m)/2
(2) some value v,op(pwq) = v for each string w over Q of length _<m, p records v.
The second requirement is very important, which solves your question.